# Play Framework - Using Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, playframework, playframework-2.0

I downloaded the following Play framework Template. 
https://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-spring-data-jpa

I found that **"index"** function in the template was a non-static function while usually on in play the "index" function is usually a static function.

What has changed with the inclusion of Spring-Data-JPA that the function is no longer static ?

Answer (score 0):

You realise that you are downloading a `Scala` `Play 2.0` version right? `Scala` doesn't have `static` keyword as in Java. What you are looking at is the `Typesafe Activator` that is a quick way to bootstrap Scala projects according to templates.

Comment: I m using Play + Java .. not scala

Answer (score 0):

i guess you havn't seen *@controller* rather controller in

```
/routes GET / @controllerApplication.index
```

Rather

```
/routes GET / controllerApplication.index
```

keywork *@* is using to exclude static acces, and i will update my answer after getting the reason behind this.

Comment: This is the reason https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Dependency-injecting-controllers